# Replace for each is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a css style guide with jekyll, I have a small problem with jQuery at the moment

Basically I need a function which will inject styles directly in the live page. This solution looked the best for my project.

My function works for 1 item, but not for each item in a loop. I don't get why, it seems I overlooked something ?

Here is my html markup

```
<div id="starterkit" class="field-style">

    <a href="#" title="Lien basique">Lien basique</a>
    <pre><code class="css">a {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    text-decoration: none;
}</code></pre>
    <hr/>

    <a href="#" title="Lien visité" class="link-visited">Lien visité</a>
    <pre><code class="css">a {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    text-decoration: none;
}</code></pre>
    <hr/>

    <a href="#" title="Lien hover" class="link-hovered">Lien hover</a>
    <pre><code class="css">a {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    text-decoration: underline;
}</code></pre>
    <hr/>

    <a href="#" title="Lien actif" class="link-active">Lien actif</a>
    <pre><code class="css">a {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    text-decoration: underline;
}</code></pre>
    <hr/>

    <a href="#" title="Lien focused" class="link-focused">Lien focused</a>
    <pre><code class="css">a {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    text-decoration: underline;
    outline: thin dotted;
}</code></pre>
    <hr/>

</div>
```

and here is my js

```
$(function() {
    $('.field-style a').each(function() {
        var base = $('this').next('pre').children('code').text();
        replaced = base.replace(/ |{|}|^a|\r?\n|\r/g,'');
        $('this').attr('style', replaced);
    })
});
```

Comment: Taking all the spaces out of the CSS source will break things like `outline: thin dotted;`

Comment: yes just experienced it after correcting the typo. Guess I have to think about my regex

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `$('this')` with `$(this)` without quotes. The `this` is a reserved keyword, referring to the current object. So your code will be:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.field-style a').each(function() {
    var base = $(this).next('pre').children('code').text();
    replaced = base.replace(/ |{|}|^a|\r?\n|\r/g,'');
    $(this).attr('style', replaced);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here

```
var base = $('this').next('pre').children('code').text();
        _____^____^______
```

It should be like:

```
var base = $(this).next('pre').children('code').text();
```